# Java ResultSet getString strange behavior

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have the following code

```
resultSet.getString("KOD")
```

which works perfectly in my test environment with "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production". However, it does not work in "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production", which is used in production.
Somehow it returns null, while it should return string value. 
If I query information in sqldeveloper it shows that there is information in column.

What  is going on here?

EDIT.
Column definitions slightly differ

```
KOD           NUMBER, // my test environment

KOD           VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), // production
```

Comment: What if you use an index (`getString(1)`) to access it?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the exact same query on both?

Comment: Not mane databases support this. Even JDBC did not support it. Check version of your JDBC drivers in both environments. Simply by executing JDBC driver as .jar file `java -jar ojdbc6.jar`. You should also avoid using CamelCase in column/table names, this can be cause of many headaches.

Comment: can you show us the underlying query ?

Comment: The following query is used SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE CLI_CODE='6270156'

Comment: well, I'd avoid the "SELECT *" makes accessing columns by index unreliable, can you edit your question and add a DESCR Table_name ? I'd like to see how the colum is defined on both your test env and prod env. It's perfectly legit resultSet.getString(..) returns a null, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @ibre5041 All JDBC drivers that I know support retrieving values by column name, and it has been in the specification since JDBC 1 and drivers are **required** to support it.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli I rolled back your edit. Please refrain from making questions harder to read by adding excessive bolding and italicizing of product names.

Comment: @R_Linus please add also the whole code you use to open the resultset (including the creation of statement/prepared statement and the fetch loop), I suspect there's something else behind your problem. And be sure you've not just modified data in SQLDeveloper and simply forget to COMMIT the changes :)

Comment: Are you able to get other fields for that same query?